# Using tuples in WHERE...IN

Tags: neo4j

I am failing to understand some behaviour and was hoping somebody here can explain it. If I run the Neo4j query:

```
MATCH (node1-[:depends*]->node2) 
WITH [node1.name, node2.name] as dependencies
return dependencies
```

I get a list of tuples of node1, node2 showing all the tuples in which node1 depends on node2 somewhere in the graph.

If I do the following query, I would expect all tuples in dependencies to be returned but instead I get an empty list:

```
MATCH (node1-[:depends*]->node2) 
WITH [node1.name, node2.name] as dependencies
return dependencies
MATCH n1--n2
WHERE ([n1.name,n2.name] IN dependencies)
return n1,n2
```

Now how can I use dependencies in a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `MATCH` clauses can follow one another in the same query, so this might work for you:

```
MATCH (node1-[:depends*]->node2) 
WITH [node1.name, node2.name] as dependencies
MATCH n1--n2
WHERE ([n1.name,n2.name] IN dependencies)
return n1,n2;
```